# How to name class instances after an iterable keys?

Tags: python, class, instance, loops

I'd like to create instances of classes getting their names from list values or dictionaries keys or values. Basically what I'd like to do is:

```
iter = ['foo', 'bar']
for a in iter:
    a = Cls()
```

and get foo and bar instances of Cls() class instead of having instance referenced by a updated at each loop.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So you want `foo` and `bar` to be local variables?  Or is Cédric's answer okay?

Comment: If what Ray wrote is, what you are looking for, then the answer is: You better don't!

Answer (score 7):

Maybe with a dictionnary :

```
iter = ['foo', 'bar']
result = {}
for a in iter:
    result[a] = Cls()
```

And in result you'll have `{ 'foo' : instance_of_Cls, 'bar' : instance_of_Cls}`

Comment: Shorter: `result = dict((name, Cls()) for name in iter)`. +1.

Comment: @cedric this is what I'm using but I'd like to have foo.attr and foo.meth instead of result['foo'].attr etc. This is much readable and avoids messing with wrapping containers. Thank you anyway.

Comment: @Silopolis : to do what you want, you'll have to modify your locals() dictionnary, and this is not a good solution... Why your variables have to be defined by strings ?

Comment: @cedric: actually, they don't "have to" as my code is running with the dict_of_objects trick but I wished I could make it clearer and had liked to be able to create series of objects which names are only known at config/runtime without the container hack... But this leads me to the question: if it had been possible, could I then easily access the list of instances ? reading this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/328851/python-printing-all-instances-of-a-class , it seems that embedding instances in a container is way easier. Thanks a lot :-)

Comment: ... and finally, reading http://docs.python.org/library/weakref.html, IIUC, this could be even better to use `weakref.WeakValueDictionary()` in this case so that the list is dynamic and the objects can be garbage collected.

Answer (score -1):

You could use dynamic code evaluation.

```
inst1 = eval("foo()")
inst2 = eval(a + "()")
inst3 = eval(a)()
```

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood the question.

Comment: My problem was getting inst1/2/3 from a list or dict. My question also applies if you'd wanted to create a series of dicts, or lists or whatever, getting their names from another container.