# Return all instances of one class

Tags: python, python-2.5

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Printing all instances of a class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/328851/printing-all-instances-of-a-class)

Is there a way to return every instance of a special class?
I'd like to get some attributes of every object and afterwards delete the object.

Comment: @Alex: `locals()` might be more apt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the class one you are writing yourself?

- Yes:  design it to keep track of its instances -- then you can query that cache
- No: no good way.

Here is a short example of keeping track of instances:

```
class Tracker(object):
    instances = list()
    def __init__(self):
        self.__class__.instances.append(self)
    @classmethod
    def projeny(cls):
        print "There are currently %d instances of Tracker" % len(cls.instances)
        for instance in cls.instances:
            print instance


t1 = Tracker()
t2 = Tracker()
Tracker.projeny()
t3 = Tracker()
Tracker.projeny()
```

which gives us:

```
There are currently 2 instances of Tracker
<__main__.Tracker object at 0x02237A30>
<__main__.Tracker object at 0x02237AD0>
There are currently 3 instances of Tracker
<__main__.Tracker object at 0x02237A30>
<__main__.Tracker object at 0x02237AD0>
<__main__.Tracker object at 0x02237AF0>
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/328882/208880) for a robust implementation.

Comment: Yes I write the class myself. Could you explain what you mean by "keep track of instances"?