# Operations of class python

Tags: python, class, oop, instance

I an new to object oriented python coding. And recently working on them.

Suppose that i have a code like:

```
class Student(object):
    def __init__(self, name, age, job):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.job = job
```

if i pass  instance to it like:

```
a = Student('Ram', 12, False)
b = Student('Hira', 34, True)
```

Then i can uses class attributes on a and b like:

```
>>>a.name
Ram
>>>b.age
34
```

is it possible that i can access instances like:

```
>>>z=Student()
>>>z.name
Ram
Hira
>>>z.age
12
34
```

Any idea ??

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do at all.

Comment: @timgeb He's trying to get the attributes of all instances that he created.

Comment: There is no built-in way to do this. You would have to put the instances in a list and have a function `age`, for instance, that iterates through the list and prints (or returns a list) of the instance's age. Alternatively, you could use list comprehension (look at Klaus' answer) - arguably a better strategy.

Comment: @pushkin aah, that makes sense

Comment: @pushkin can you explain it  by example. Thanks

Comment: I think what you are looking for is *inside-out objects* (Google it).  The technique was used in Perl, but rarely (if ever) needed in Python.  Basically you hold a dictionary for each attribute as a class variable.  The key is the `id` of each object.  Most Pythonistas would consider them horrible.  Ask yourself why you need this feature.  Maybe your design need to be reconsidered?

Comment: @cdarke Django uses this kind of method in creating and accessing model. I am using Dajngo but somehow i have to create that kind of structure.

Comment: @KHUSHALSINGH Look at Klaus' answer.

Comment: @pushkin  got it. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Not like that. But you can store the students in a list and then use list comprehensions on it:

```
students = []
students.append(Student('Ram', 12, False))
students.append(Student('Hira', 34, True))

ages = [s.age for s in students]
```

This will give you a list of all ages.

You can even add a condition:

```
adult_ages = [s.age for s in students if s.age >= 18]
```

Comment: @Klaus: I think we can do this using "weakref"

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can! Define an arbitrary attribute `list` in the class and using `weakref` access all of the class's attributes.

`weakref` is used to create weak references to an object(a class instance, ideally) through `proxy` method. The magic line means that get all the attributes of this class and append it to the list(here, instances).

Here is the code:

```
import weakref as wr
class A:
    instances = []
    def __init__(self, name, age, job):
        self.__class__.instances.append(wr.proxy(self)) #magic
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.job = job

a1 = A('mario', 23, 'student')
a2 = A('cocoo', 25, 'student')
a3 = A('romeo', 27, 'student')

for instance in A.instances:
    print(instance.name)

for instance in A.instances:
    print(instance.age)
```

Sample output:

```
mario
cocoo
romeo
23
25
27
```

Comment: @KHUSHALSINGH, http://stackoverflow.com/a/9460070/2141635 this answer seems to be taken from there

Comment: @kmario23, you should explain the magic and link to the answer you got the code from

Comment: @PadraicCunningham This answer is motivated from that example but not an exact copy.

Comment: @kmario23, it is very similar, anyway I think it is  good to give credit to the original author, you should also maybe expand on how it works as it is pretty unclear.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham You're right! This is my current understanding. Can you please edit it if you have more info? I would love to learn more from guys like you :)