# Python - Exclusive attribute value for object?

Tags: python, attributes

Let say I have this class:

```
class A(object):
 def __init__(self, one=None):
   self.one = one
```

So every time you create `A` object, you can assign `one` attribute. But only the last object assigned not false value gets to keep it.

For example:

```
a = A('a')
b = A('b')
c = A()
print a
print b
print c
----
None
b
None
```

Now these objects are also actual records (rows) in database, so those could be accessed later.

What could be a good pattern (if there is) to set such attribute dynamically (unsetting attribute for older objects)?

Comment: Can't you just use the factory pattern? Then you could keep track of the last object that has one set and unset as necessary.

Comment: Keep a list of instances (see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/q/328851/3001761) and use a property to implement your setting/unsetting logic (see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/q/17330160/3001761).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could store an instance in a class variable and unset the previous one in the `__init__`.

```
class A(object):
    obj = None
    def __init__(self, one=None):
        self.one = one
        if self.one:
            if A.obj:
                A.obj.one = None
            A.obj = self
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.one)
```

Result:

```
>>> a = A('a')
>>> b = A('b')
>>> c = A()
>>> print a
None
>>> print b
b
>>> print c
None
```

Comment: @Andrius - Please note the edit here. I don't know why I initially wrote it to store a whole `list` when only the last one was needed.