# Python - Find an instance of a class, based on a value of an attribute

Tags: python, class, instance

I want to find an instance of a class, where an attribute has a certain value:

```
import numpy as np
import inspect
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class Frame():
    def __init__(self, img, idx):
        self.image = img
        self.idx = idx

for i in range(10):
    img = np.random.randint(0, high=255, size=(720, 1280, 3), dtype=np.uint8) # generate a random, noisy image
    Frame(img, i)

# Pseudo Code below:
frame = inspect.getmembers(Frame, idx=5) # find an instance of a class where the index is equal to 5
plt.imshow(frame.img)
```

Comment: Why are you not saving the instances you created into a list?

Comment: You are creating and then discarding the `Frame` instances.

Comment: From your example it looks like you are mixing two things: defining a Frame object (which contains an image) and defining a *collection* of Frames (which contains an index of frames). 

So it looks like a xy problem: you probably just need to save Frame instances in a dictionary/list and then access the Frame you need

Comment: And what is wrong with your code? What do you get?...

Comment: The above is just an example. Yes, I can put them into a list, but that won't help me if the variable is not index, but a "string" for example.

Comment: In that case use a dictionary

Comment: As stated in the code comments, the second to last line is a pseudo code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your example it looks like you are mixing two things: defining a Frame object (which contains an image) and defining a collection of Frames (which contains multiple frames, indexed so you can access them as you prefer).

So it looks like a [xy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) problem: you probably just need to save Frame instances in a dictionary/list type of collection and then access the Frame you need.

Anyway, you can access the value of an attribute of an object using [getattr](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr).

```
all_frames = []

for i in range(10):
    img = np.random.randint(0, high=255, size=(720, 1280, 3), dtype=np.uint8) # generate a random, noisy image
    all_frames.append(Frame(img, i))

frames_to_plot = [frame for frame in all_frames if getattr(frame, index) == 5]

for frame in frames_to_plot:
    plt.imshow(frame.img)
```

Comment: I don't want to look for the instance in the loop. I want to be able to access instances outside the loop, by referring to some of their properties, whitout saving them into a list. The instances exist in the memmory, but not as a variable (like your "a_class"), but under some self generated string of randome letters and numbers

Comment: is there any specific reason you don't want to save it to variable?

Comment: I am creating an instance for every frame in a video. Later, I am manipulating the images and change the values of some of the attributes. Finally, I need to find the frames that have some of this parameters in a specific range / have a certain value. Even if I save it to a variable, it wouldn't make any sense, as the variable names cannot reflect the information that I use to filter all frames later

Comment: Understood. as you can access the attributes using getattr, you can save all frames to a list (or any collection) and later filter/select them based on the attributes of the instance.  Does the new solution work better for you?

Comment: Thanks! Both your and Ev. Kounis answers are correct, however you introduced the list of objects, which is the exact solution I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this `class`:

```
class Frame():
    def __init__(self, img, idx):
        self.image = img
        self.idx = idx
```

and two instances:

```
a = Frame('foo', 1)
b = Frame('bar', 2)
```

You can find the one with `idx=1` like so:

```
import gc


def find_em(classType, attr, targ):
    return [obj.image for obj in gc.get_objects() if isinstance(obj, classType) and getattr(obj, attr)==targ]

print(find_em(Frame, 'idx', 1))  # -> ['foo']
```

Note that if you have a big code with lots of objects created in memory, `gc.get_objects()` will be big and thus this approach rather slow and inefficient. The `gc.get_objects()` idea I got from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/328882/6162307).

Does this answer your question?

Comment: Thanks, that answers my question. However, I now realize that my assumption that the instances are kept in the memory is wrong, so a list will be still needed if I don't save them to a variable. I selected FLab answer, as he reflected on that.