# making a static method within the class to store object name that is created?

Tags: python-3.x, class

```
class myClass():

   @staticmethod
   def all_object():
       pass
   myInstances = []
   def __init__(self, myStr01, myStr02):
       self.myStr01 = myStr01
       self.myStr02 = myStr02
       self.__class__.myInstances.append(self)

myObj01 = myClass("Foo", "Bar")
myObj02 = myClass("FooBar",  "Baz")
```

Basically I want to make a static method that return a list when calling `myClass.all_object()` that store `myObj01` and `myObj02` into a list like `[myObj01,myObj02]`. And when more object is created it keeps append onto that list.

I don't really know how to actually access the name of the object since it is not stored in the `__dict__()` method within the class.

Comment: Do you want the identifier (the variable name), or a reference to your object?  I don't think you can do the former. What are you trying to do with that list?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Printing all instances of a class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/328851/printing-all-instances-of-a-class)

Comment: You can see nearly same solutions [here](http://effbot.org/pyfaq/how-do-i-get-a-list-of-all-instances-of-a-given-class.htm)

Comment: Thx for the help!

Comment: thx for the help!