# Print all class instances stored in a list

Tags: python

I am trying to create a list of N instances of class Name and then call back a parameter of that instance. My code is below.

I get an error:
Exception has occurred: AttributeError
'str' object has no attribute 'get_name'

and am not sure how to fix it. Any ideas?
Thank you

```
class Name:
    global listName 
    listName = []

    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name = name
        listName.append (self.name)

    @property
    def get_name (self):
        print  (self.name)


for i in range (10):
    Name(f"Name{i}")

for i in range (10):
    listName[i].get_name
```

Comment: `Name.listName` ... if you want to use your class variable. And you store strings in it - not the instances of Name (aka `self` - wich you could store instead). Strings do not have any `get_name` function - and lastly: ` listName[i].get_name` dos not call a function. Please look into basics: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/ for classes and functions and how to call them

Comment: Replace `listName.append (self.name)` with `listName.append(self)`

Comment: Btw you may be interested in [Printing all instances of a class](https://stackoverflow.com/q/328851/1782792).

Comment: @PatrickArtner but `listName` is a global variable. So it's not part of the class, right?

Comment: It is a class variable if you indent it under the class - making it `global` as well is ... not needed at all: read [instance-variables-vs-class-variables-in-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2714573/instance-variables-vs-class-variables-in-python)

Comment: If you want `listName` to be global, then don't define it inside the `class` statement. `listName` inside a *method* will already refer to the global scope, since it's not already defined locally.

Comment: If you want `listName` to be a class attribute, then drop the `global` statement.

Answer (score 3):

You did not append the instance of `Name` to your list, you only appended the name as a string.

See this line in the constructor of `Name`:

`listName.append (self.name)`

That line has to be

`listName.append(self)`

for your code to work.

**Also:**

As Patrick Artner pointed out in the comments, `listName[i].get_name` is not a function call. You have to add parentheses to call a function, like this:

`listName[i].get_name()`

**Another thing:**

As I just learned myself, you made `listName` a class variable by declaring it in the body of `Name`. You have to access it as `Name.listName`. The `global listName` statement is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

listName.append(self) is correct.
get_name is worked instead of get_name().

```
class Name:
    global listName 
    listName = []

    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name = name
        listName.append (self)

    @property
    def get_name (self):
        print (self.name)

for i in range (10):
    Name(f"Name{i}")

for i in range (10):
    listName[i].get_name


Name0
Name1
Name2
Name3
Name4
Name5
Name6
Name7
Name8
Name9
```