# How to iterate over all the instances of a class?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I know this has been asked before, but I couldn't find an answer for my problem and all of the answers got me more confused.

So I created a class called Books, which takes as input a file location and the name of the file, and has a method called countwords which counts the words of the file.

I created a bunch of instances(are they called like this?) of this class, but I want to iterate the method CountWords on all of them. This is my code:

```
class Books():
    def __init__(self, path, fullname):
        self.path     = path
        self.fullname = fullname

    def count_words(self):
        try:
            with open(self.path + self.fullname, encoding='utf-8') as f:
                contents = f.read()
        except FileNotFoundError:
            print(f"Sorry, the file {self.fullname} doesn't exist.")
        else:
            words     = contents.split()
            num_words = len(words)
            print(f"The file {self.fullname} has about {num_words}" 
                  f"words.")             

alice        = Books("text_files/", 'alice.txt')
siddharta    = Books("text_files/", 'siddhartha.txt')
mobydick     = Books('text_files/', 'moby_dick.txt')
little_women = Books('text_files/', 'little_women.txt')
```

I want to write something like this:

```
for book in Books.list():
    book.count_words()
```

and get:

```
 The file alice.txt has about 29465 words. 
 The file siddhartha.txt has about 1500 words.
 The file moby_dick.txt has about 215830 words. 
 The file little_women.txt has about 189079 words.
```

Printing the words count of all the instances associated with the Books() class, how can I achieve this? thank you!

**EDIT**:
I have tried different approaches but this is the one I'm using now:

1. first one is importing weakref(don't know what this is for).
2. Then adding an empty list at the beginning of the class.
3. after that use: self.__class__LISTNAME_append(weakref.proxy(self)) at the end of the def init
4. Then you can loop through the LISTNAME.

**code:**

```
# 1 
import weakref

class Book():
  # 2
  book_list = []
  def __init__(self, path, fullname):
      self.path = path
      self.fullname = fullname
      # 3
      self.__class__.book_list.append(weakref.proxy(self))

  def count_words(self):
      try:
          with open(self.path + self.fullname, encoding='utf-8') as f:
              contents = f.read()
      except FileNotFoundError:
          print(f"Sorry, the file {self.fullname} doesn't exist.")
      else:
          words = contents.split()
          num_words = len(words)
          print(f"The file {self.fullname} has about {num_words} "
                f"words. ")

alice = Book("text_files/", 'alice.txt')

siddharta = Book("text_files/", 'siddhartha.txt')

mobydick = Book('text_files/', 'moby_dick.txt')

little_women = Book('text_files/', 'little_women.txt')

# 4
for book in Book.book_list:
  book.count_words()
```

Comment: You might want to take a look at this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/328851/printing-all-instances-of-a-class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than having your class keep references to all the instances that have been created, I suggest you define your data *first*, and then create a collection of instances from that data.

For example:

```
book_paths = [('text_files/', 'alice.txt'),
              ('text_files/', 'siddharta.txt'),
              ('text_files/', 'moby_dick.txt'),
              ('text_files/', 'little_women.txt')]

books = []

for path, name in book_paths:
    book = Books(path, name)
    books.append(book)
    book.count_words()
```

You can also later iterate over `books` to do whatever you want. Another way to do this, using a `list` comprehension:

```
books = [Books(path, name) for path, name in book_paths]

for book in books:
    book.count_words()
```

Answer (score 2):

All you have to do is create a class variable which will store the book information when the instance is instantiated.

And then expose a class level method which return this list when `Books.list` gets called.

Here is the code for the same

```
class Books(object):
```

> ```
>     _books_list = list()
> ```

```
    def __init__(self, path, fullname):
        self.path = path
        self.fullname = fullname
        self._books_list.append(self.path + self.fullname)

    def count_words(self):
        try:
            with open(self.path + self.fullname, encoding='utf-8') as f:
                contents = f.read()
        except FileNotFoundError:
            print(f"Sorry, the file {self.fullname} doesn't exist.")
        else:
            words = contents.split()
            num_words = len(words)
            print(f"The file {self.fullname} has about {num_words}"
                  f"words.")
```

> ```
>     @classmethod
>     def list():
>         return self._books_list
> ```

```
alice = Books("text_files/", 'alice.txt')
siddharta = Books("text_files/", 'siddhartha.txt')
mobydick = Books('text_files/', 'moby_dick.txt')
little_women = Books('text_files/', 'little_women.txt')
```

Answer (score 1):

that's the wrong way to approach the problem.

I suggest you create a dictionary of classes instead, with filename as key:

instead of:

```
alice = Books("text_files/", 'alice.txt')
siddharta = Books("text_files/", 'siddhartha.txt')
mobydick = Books('text_files/', 'moby_dick.txt')
little_women = Books('text_files/', 'little_women.txt')
```

do:

```
books_dict = {name:Books('text_files/',name+".txt") for name in ["alice","siddhartha","moby_dick","little_women"}
```

Now you have a dictionary of `Books` instances. You can now iterate on it like this:

```
for book_name,book_instance in books_dict.items():
    print(book_name,book_instance)
```

If you want to "unregister" an instance, just do:

```
books_dict.pop("alice")
```

Better not create x variables for x instances. Use a federating structure.

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate your effort to help, but your response causes the following error: "for book_name,book_instance in books_dict.items():
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'items'

Comment: my bad, see the correction. Dictionary comprehension, not list comprehension.

Answer (score 1):

Judging by your variable, it might be easier to comprehend by naming the class `Book`:

```
class Book():
    def __init__(self, path, fullname):
        self.path = path
        self.fullname = fullname

    def count_words(self):
        try:
            with open(self.path + self.fullname, encoding='utf-8') as f:
                contents = f.read()
        except FileNotFoundError:
            print(f"Sorry, the file {self.fullname} doesn't exist.")
        else:
            words = contents.split()
            num_words = len(words)
            print(f"The file {self.fullname} has about {num_words}" 
                  f"words.")
```

make the instances of books as you've described

```
alice = Book("text_files/", 'alice.txt')
siddharta = Book("text_files/", 'siddhartha.txt')
mobydick = Book('text_files/', 'moby_dick.txt')
little_women = Book('text_files/', 'little_women.txt')
```

and add them into a list referenced as `books`:

```
books = [alice, siddhartha, mobydick, little_women]
```

then you can iterate over the list calling the `count_words` method on each book