# How can I keep track of all the objects I created of a class, in a list in the driver program?

Tags: python-3.x, class

I need to make a list that tracks the objects that have been called of a certain class.
These objects need to be accessible and display information when called from the list.

```
pizza2 = DeluxePizza("small",1,1,1,1,1)
pizza2.__str__()
pizza3 = DeluxePizza("medium",1,2,3,0,2)
pizza3.__str__()
pizza4 = DeluxePizza("large",1,0,1,0,5)
pizza4.__str__()
```

Whenever a new object is called, they need to be stored in the list like this-

```
pizzas = [pizza2, pizza3, pizza4]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Printing all instances of a class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/328851/printing-all-instances-of-a-class)

Comment: No, not really, but thanks though. I want to store the instances as and how I call them in the main program in a list, which when I view later should allow me to access that instance.

Comment: That's exactly what the answers on the dupe describe, how to automatically have a list of all of the instances.

Comment: I found my way around it through one of the answers. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to do something along the lines of the following:

```
pizza_orders = []
pizzas = [("small",1,1,1,1,1),("medium",1,2,3,0,2),("large",1,0,1,0,5)]
for pza in pizzas:
    pizza_orders.append(DeluxePizza("small",pza[0],pza[1],pza[2],pza[3],pza[4]))
for po in pizza_orders:
    print(po)
```

pizza_orders is a list of DeluxePizza Class instances
pizzas is a list of the specific instantiations of the Deluxe Pizza class you want to order
When you execute the po in pizza_orders list you will get the list of orders for the three pizzas

Comment: This does work, but if I keep calling more objects per se, how can I keep appending them into the list automatically when they're called? Or should I append the object itself?

Comment: As I have shown just append the object itself.  Of course if you need to refer to a specific object rather than iterate through all of the objects, you will either have to remember the index of the specific object or otherwise create a variable that is the object.

Comment: I made them all append as objects in a list, it works somehow. Thanks!

Comment: If you want to grow as a python programmer, you should probably figure out why it works.  Not just accept the fact that it does, you will see this form many times in programming.

Comment: What I did, was basically call the object through a function and provide the parameters for it through inputs. I did end up making two different lists, to store the objects and the attributes separately.